# CSV Date format for Salesforce Date (or Date Time)

Tags: datetime, csv, python

I am trying to insert data from csv file into Salesforce (using Python file).

Bottom is portion of Python script to fetch the data from csv file and into Salesforce database.

```
for line in file: 
    line = line.strip()
    line_parts = line.split(",")

    if not line_parts[0] in 'Date':
        sf.Table__c.create({'Date__c': line[0], 'Survey__c': line[1]})
```

The output format of 'Date' is  7/23/2017 .

What should be the format inside csv file so that it would take into "Date" or "Date Time" format in Salesforce?

I am trying to use Date and Time such as "7/23/2017  9:00:00 AM".

When I tried with this format in csv, it generated this error

```
Response content: [{u'errorCode': u'JSON_PARSER_ERROR', u'message': 
u'Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING value Date or 
request may be missing a reuqired field at [line:1, column:17]'}}
```

I even tried with simple "7/23/2017" format, and still getting the same error.

I guess the challenge is how to format the cell as acceptable format as illustrated on the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

The "Date" field acceptable formats

- YYYY-MM-DD

AND

"Date Time" field acceptable formats

- YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
- YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
- YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ

Comment: I tried to find these formats, but I do not find that at CSV file.

Comment: I dont understand ->" I do not find that at CSV file "

Comment: I am looking at Format Cell options inside Excel/CSV file, but I cannot find these.

Comment: To change the date format, you need to open the spreadsheet, highlight the column and right-click and select 'Format Cells'. Choose 'Date; then highlight 03/14/01, while that is highlighted click on 'Custom'.

Comment: I got to where it is 03/14/01, but when I went to 'Custom' , I do not see option of  YYYY-MM-DD from the list, but I typed in YYYY-MM-DD. Now, it is indicated as 2017-07-23 on csv file. I saved the file. But, when I ran the Python file, I still get the same error.

Comment: if you can upload your python script and the library you are using to do so, it could be helpful - maybe in another question and mention this one in a link.

Comment: I modified this post with some of my Python code included.

Comment: are you using simple python?

Comment: yes. I do not use library on this one.

Comment: is your date a string value when you fetch the variable from the list line[0] ? if you are not sure "print type(line[0]) "

Comment: make sure your field type matches the format as well

Comment: The type of data from csv file for (7/23/2017) column is 'str'

Comment: Your format is still invalid