# Can't get date right in CSV for article import

Tags: knowledge, import, articles

I am trying to import articles into Salesforce using Import Articles. I've resolved most of the issues, except the date time. I see from this [article](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185498/csv-date-format-for-salesforce-date-or-date-time) that the acceptable date formats are:

- YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
- YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
- YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ

I have tried the following patterns in my csv and nothing has been accepted.

- 2012-07-06 00:00:01
- 2012-07-06T00:00:01
- 2012-07-06T00:00:01.000Z

I've stripped down my csv to only one article and only the fields that are required.

```
rnAnswerId__c,Channels,datacategorygroup.Support_Products,Environment__c,Title,RightNow_Created_Date__c,Issue__c,Resolution__c,Cause__c
1167201,application+csp,Test_Product,data/1167201.html,Test Article,2012-07-06 00:00:01,data/1167201.html,data/1167201.html,data/1167201.html
```

I've even tried adding quotes. I've tried escaping the quotes a la '2012-07-06T00:00:01' nothing is working. I need a date that works.

Comment: Using this format `2012-07-06T00:00:00.00Z` or `2012-07-06T00:00:00.000Z` import works? And have you referred this document: [Format the 'Date' and 'Date Time' data in a CSV file](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325035&type=1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Raul. Dataloader export of an article created today was 2022-05-05T19:36:52.000Z, but when I formatted my import date to 2012-07-06T00:00:50.000Z it was rejected.

Comment: Could you check csv in notepad to verify if the formatting is retained, sometime Microsoft excel's formatting messes up.

Comment: While I generated the csv in excel, I've been editing the different date formats in Notepad++

Comment: We work lots of dataloads and this format always works 2012-07-06T00:00:50Z for datetime and 2012-07-06 for dates.

Comment: What version of Data Loader are you using, and what's the specific error message you're getting?  Are you sure you're using the standard ASCII hyphen character instead of the Unicode em-dash or en-dash characters?  You can check by pasting the value into a Unicode decoder website.

Comment: We aren't using Data Loader. We're using Import Articles in the Salesforce setup. We've tried the  2012-07-06T00:00:50Z for the datetime. What does your datetime in the .properties file look like?

Comment: Well, that should work.  Have you opened a case with Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening a case with Salesforce, it turned out that opening the CSV in Excel was formatting the date.

The date field needs to be in this format

```
2012-07-06 00:00:50
```

The properties need to be in this format

```
DateTimeFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 
CSVEncoding=ISO8859_15_FDIS
```